# Find the value of $n$ so that $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$ may be the geometric mean between $a$ and $b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, means, geometric-series

> **Question:**
>
> Find the value of $n$ so that $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$ may be the geometric mean between $a$ and $b$.

**My approach:**

We know geometric mean between any two numbers $a$ and $b$ is given by $\sqrt{ab}$. By some processing in my brain I tried $n=-\frac{1}{2}$ and the result matched with the formula to find the geometric mean.

I wish to know is there any other disciplined approach for this problem?

Kindly guide me in this regard.

Comment: First of all, this is not AP. a and b are arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: "By some processing in my brain"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a>b$

$\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n} = \sqrt{ab}\\ \implies a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}= a^{n+1/2}b^{1/2} + a^{1/2}b^{n+1/2} 
\\\implies a^{n+1/2}(a^{1/2}-b^{1/2}) - b^{n+1/2}(a^{1/2}-b^{1/2})=0\\
\implies (a^{1/2}-b^{1/2})(a^{n+1/2}-b^{n+1/2})=0
$

Since $a\ne b$, above equation forces $a^{n+1/2} = b^{n+1/2} \implies n+1/2=0$

Comment: yw:) I remember seeing similar formulas formulas for AM and HM too..

Comment: Are you preparing for JEE? or Did you once?

Comment: Ahh no my engg days are behind me. I'm about to ask you the same haha. Are you? I remember seeing these formulas in some youtube video taught by a very pretty girl

Comment: Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmFvDLHz-7Y

Comment: Yes, I am currently preparing. Thank you for the link. I will watch it after some time.

Comment: Nice.. seeing you pause to ponder on questions like these, I bet you're definitely going to make it! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your wishes sir.

Comment: @AgentS I am preparing for JEE, I  am currently in grade 11, I have already watched that video, and other videos on sequences and series, I found it very helpful, and I recommend everyone to watch that video.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the following:

\begin{align*}
\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+\,\dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}=\sqrt{ab} &\iff \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=a^n\sqrt{ab}+b^n\sqrt{ab}\\
&\iff \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+ a^n\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})+b^n\sqrt{b}(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})=0\\
&\iff \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+a^n\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=b^n\sqrt{b}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am unable to obtain the final answer from your steps. Please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: **Hint**: you can eliminate $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ because the statement is for all $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$. Then form a power of $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Thanks. Your method was also useful. If I had the opportunity to accept more that one answer, I would have accepted yours. Thanks a lot for spending your time.

Comment: @Intellex No problem it's a pleasure :)
"was also useful" well it's the same as the one in the accepted question that was posted 6 mins after mine, with the difference of guiding instead of giving the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=2b$ in  $$\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n} = \sqrt{ab}$$

and simplify you get $$\frac {2^{n+1 }+1}{2^{n}+1} = \sqrt 2$$

$$ 2^{n+1}+1=2^{1/2}+2^{n+\frac {1}{2}} $$

The only solution is $n=-1/2$

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $a,b>0$ and $a\ne b$, the function$${a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\over a^{n}+b^{n}}={a+b u^n\over 1+u^n}$$is absolutely increasing where $u={b\over a}$. There the answer $n=-{1\over 2}$ is the only such solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know two things : (1) How did you determine the expression is strictly increasing?   (2) How did you finalize $n=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Sure. For $u>1$ we have $${a+b u^n\over 1+u^n}=b-{b-a\over 1+u^n}$$which is strictly increasing since $u^n$ is strictly increasing. The case $u<1$ is also similar. Since the GM of two numbers is a **fixed constant given the numbers**, we cannot have more than a value of $n$ for which the value of ${a+b u^n\over 1+u^n}$ remains the same. That's all. Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. If I had the opportunity to accept more that one answer, I would have accepted yours. Thanks a lot for spending your time.

Comment: Your welcome and best regard!!

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}\right)$ is G.M. between $a$ and $b$.

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^{n}+b^{n}}=a^{(1 / 2)} b^{(1 / 2)} \quad\left[G . M\right.$. between $\left.a \& b=a^{(1 / 2)} b^{(1 / 2)}\right]$
$\Leftrightarrow a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=a^{n+(1 / 2)} b^{(1 / 2)}+a^{(1 / 2)} b^{n+(1 / 2)}$
$\Leftrightarrow a^{n+1}-a^{n+(1 / 2)} b^{(1 / 2)}=a^{(1 / 2)} b^{n+(1 / 2)}-b^{n+1}$
$\Leftrightarrow a^{n+(1 / 2)}\left[a^{(1 / 2)}-b^{(1 / 2)}\right]=b^{n+(1 / 2)}\left[a^{(1 / 2)}-b^{(1 / 2)}\right]$
$\Leftrightarrow a^{n+(1 / 2)}=b^{n+(1 / 2)} \quad\left[\because a^{(1 / 2)}-b^{(1 / 2)} \neq 0\right.$, since $\left.a \neq b\right]$
$\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n+(1 / 2)}=1=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{0}$
$\Leftrightarrow n+\frac{1}{2}=0$
$\Leftrightarrow n=-\frac{1}{2}$